# Polymer 1.x: Obervers bug? Fix or Workaround?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

*Let me start by saying, I'm like 90% sure this is a bug with the Polymer observers system.*

Conduct the following test and notice the following unexpected behaviors:

### Test Procedure

1. [Open this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/saxewimowu/edit?html,output).
2. Toggle the `<paper-toggle-button>`.
3. Notice the `changes` variable does **not** increment as expected.
4. Enter any text into the `<paper-input>` field.
5. Notice the `changes` variable **does** increment as expected.
6. Toggle the `<paper-toggle-button>` again.
7. Notice the `changes` variable **now does** increment as expected.

Note I also observed the same problems with `<paper-dropdown-menu>` as demonstrated here with `<paper-toggle-button>` but omitted it from this question for brevity.

## Questions

> - What's going on here?
> - Is this a bug?
> - Is there any workaround or fix?

http://jsbin.com/saxewimowu/edit?html,output

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Element</title>
  <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html"></script>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/" />
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html" />
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <paper-input value="{{str::input}}"></paper-input><br />
      <paper-toggle-button checked="{{bool}}"></paper-toggle-button><br />
      <br />changes:<span>[[num]]</span><br />      
      <br />str: <span>[[str]]</span><br />
      <br />bool:<span>[[bool]]</span><br />
    </template>
    <script>
      (function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'my-element',
          observers: [
            'inputChanged(str, bool)'
          ],
          inputChanged(a, b) {
            if(! this.num){
              this.set('num', 1);
            } else {
              this.set('num', (this.num + 1) );
            }
          }
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does after both properties have a value different of `undefined` (I guess or `null`).
After you enter a text and click the toggle, each change prints `A`.
To work around assign default values to your properties.

I added

```
      properties: {
        str: {
          type: String,
          value: ''
        },
        bool: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        }            
      },
```

to your element and with this I can't reproduce your problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to observe props individually.

```
 (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        str:        {
          type:       String,
          notify:     true,
          observer:   '_somethingChanged'
        },
        bool:       {
          type:       Boolean,
          notify:     true,
          observer:   '_somethingChanged'
        }
      },
      _somethingChanged: function(evt) {
        // At this point, evt contains infos about what changed. Eg path and value.
        console.log('Something changed');
      },
    });
  })();
```

Another workaround would be to make `str` and `bool` parts of the same property (An object named `foo`) and observe `foo.*`.

```
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        foo:        {
          type:       Object,
          notify:     true,
          value:      function(){
            return {
              str:     'Default',
              bool:    false
            }
          }
        },
      },
      observers: [ '_somethingChanged(foo.*)' ],
      _somethingChanged: function() {
        // At this point, evt contains infos about what changed. Eg path and value.
        console.log('Something changed');
      },
    });
  })();
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I will add the source code and [this link to the JSBin of the accepted answer and working solution](http://jsbin.com/pufalegofe/1/edit?html,output).

http://jsbin.com/pufalegofe/1/edit?html,output

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Element</title>
  <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/samples/components/polymer/polymer.html"></script>
  <base href="http://element-party.xyz/" />
  <link rel="import" href="all-elements.html" />
</head>
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <paper-input value="{{str::input}}"></paper-input><br />
      <paper-toggle-button checked="{{bool}}"></paper-toggle-button><br />
      <br />changes:<span>[[num]]</span><br />      
      <br />str: <span>[[str]]</span><br />
      <br />bool:<span>[[bool]]</span><br />
    </template>
    <script>
      (function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'my-element',
          properties: {
            str: {
              type: String,
              value: ''
            },
            bool: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: false
            }            
          },
          observers: [
            'inputChanged(str, bool)'
          ],
          inputChanged: function(a, b) {
            if(! this.num){
              this.set('num', 1);
            } else {
              this.set('num', (this.num + 1) );
            }
          }
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```